Powershell access output of currently running exe
Is it possible in Powershell to capture the live output of a running exe in order to log and/or manipulate it as the process runs?
Context
I have an exe that runs for quite a while (oiiotool for those interested), this exe continually outputs its current progress in the form "Writing .\filename.0001.ext", "Writing ./filename.0002.ext" and so on.
If I could read each line as it is output I could instead calculate the percentage complete and display/update a progress bar.
Things I have tried
& program.exe *>&1 | foreach {Write-Host $_}
This allows for the capture and alteration of the output but will not output anything until the exe has finished running.
Start-Process program.exe -NoNewWindow -Wait
This will continually display the output as the exe runs but with no ability to capture or alter how that output is displayed. (This is what I will fall back on as it at least gives me the current progress in some form)
$process = Start-Process program.exe -NoNewWindow -PassThru -RedirectStandardOutput 'stdout.txt'
while (-not $process.HasExited){
    Get-Content 'stdout.txt' -Tail 1 | Write-Host
}

This will output nothing until the exe has finished. It seems that the process will wait until completion before writing the entire output to stdout.txt at once.
I have also tried the various New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo, New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process approaches however I can't seem to get them to work either.
Apologies if this is a duplicate however this question seems to have been asked and answered in a few different forms but none of the answers seem to work, hence this attempt at formulating the question.

you're missing -PassThru in the Start-Process attempt. It produces no output otherwise. also if the & program.exe *>&1 | foreach {Write-Host $_} attempt already failed the redirect output with Start-Process won't help either

start-process is usually wrong.

@SantiagoSquarzon I have tried both with and without -PassThru with little success. That flag seems to output the process object not the exe output. That said it does seem to at least solve the infinite loop problem with the third example, so I've updated the question to reflect that. Thanks :)
Regarding the & program.exe approach, as stated in the question it does redirect the output successfully however it does so all at once upon completion of the exe process rather than the desired effect of displaying the live output produced by the exe while it is running.
